# How can I make a bbcode decoder that turns html end tags into the bbcode end tag they started as?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, bbcode

I have some javascript that will turn
`[b]test[/b]`
into
`<span class="bbcode_bold">test</span>`

Also, this
`[i]test 2[/i]`
will turn into
`<span class="bbcode_italic">test</span>`

That works fine, but I need to be able to decode that as well. With multiple types of bbcode that all have the same end tags, how can I figure a way to identify end tags as the bbcode tag they started as?

Edit: The code I use to parse text with bbcode in it:

```
function bbencode(input){
return input
.replace(/\n/ig, '<br/>')
.replace(/\[b\]/ig, '<span class="bbcode_bold">')
.replace(/\[\/b\]/ig, '</span>')
.replace(/\[i\]/ig, '<span class="bbcode_italic">')
.replace(/\[\/i\]/ig, '</span>')
;
}
```

My problem is in the decoder:

```
function bbdecode(input){
return input
.replace(/\n/ig, "<br/>")
.replace(/<span class="bbcode_bold">/ig, "[b]")
.replace(/<\/span>/ig, "[/b]")
.replace(/<span class="bbcode_italic">/ig, "[i]")
.replace(/<\/span>/ig, "[/i]")
;
}
```

Every span end tag needs to be interpreted as the bbcode end tag that it started as but there's no way to tell the difference. I tried putting classes in the end tags but firefox doesn't allow it.

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery for this?

Comment: OK, post the jQuery you have which changes the BBcode into HTML.

Comment: OP edited. I actually didn't use any jquery for this specific function, but I do use it elsewhere. I thought my code was the easiest way.

Comment: First of all, why are you returning anything before the function is done executing?

Comment: all of those replace functions are executed on the variable input. the only semicolon is at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a comment after the  tag then test for that, e.g.:

```
function bbencode(input){
    return input
    .replace(/\n/ig, '<br/>')
    .replace(/\[b\]/ig, '<span class="bbcode_bold">')
    .replace(/\[\/b\]/ig, '</span><!--BOLD-->')
    .replace(/\[i\]/ig, '<span class="bbcode_italic">')
    .replace(/\[\/i\]/ig, '</span><!--ITALIC-->')
;
}
```